# Using ColorMatrix to Recolor System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to develop a simple image adjusting extension method that has this signature:

```
static Alter(this System.Drawing.Image, Color original, Color result);
```

I want to seed the algorithm with the current image's color and then I want to convert it to the `result` color.  So if the I pass in img.Alter(Purple, Yellow) the entire image will be skewed towards yellow.  I have this working for the most part and can do static conversions such as to grayscale and inversion, but the dynamic alteration is stumping me.

My main issue is how to determine the "difference" in color and then apply that to the ColorMatrix's RGB format.  I have a HueSaturationBrightness converter so I could potentially do some math with the GetHue(), GetSaturation() and GetBrightness() values of the passed in colors.

I'm trying to use the 40, 41 and 42 indexes of the ColorMatrix to add/subtract components to the red, green, and blue components of the original image/color.  I can't seem to get this right.

What is the best way to determine the RGB percent difference of 2 images using HSB.

Comment: Pretty unclear, I can see Yellow as the goal but what does Purple mean as the first argument?

Comment: The image is originally purple.